# How to subset a table object in R?

Tags: r

How can I subset a table based on values and return those values? This returns just indices:

```
with(chickwts, table(feed))
with(chickwts, table(feed)) > 11
which(with(chickwts, table(feed)) > 11)
```

Output

```
> with(chickwts, table(feed))
feed
   casein horsebean   linseed  meatmeal   soybean sunflower 
       12        10        12        11        14        12 
> with(chickwts, table(feed)) > 11
feed
   casein horsebean   linseed  meatmeal   soybean sunflower 
     TRUE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE      TRUE      TRUE 
> which(with(chickwts, table(feed)) > 11)
   casein   linseed   soybean sunflower 
        1         3         5         6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the computed value twice, so its useful to use an intermediate variable:

```
x <- with(chickwts, table(feed))
x[x>11]
feed
   casein   linseed   soybean sunflower 
       12        12        14        12
```

Comment: Or, with somewhat repetitious code: `with(chickwts, table(feed)[table(feed) > 11])`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an other approach making use of the `Filter` function:

```
Filter(function(x) x > 11, with(chickwts, table(feed)))
feed
   casein   linseed   soybean sunflower 
       12        12        14        12
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using **base functions**:

```
subset(data.frame(table(chickwts$feed)), Freq > 11)
```

Result:

```
       Var1 Freq
1    casein   12
3   linseed   12
5   soybean   14
6 sunflower   12
```

---

Using the **dplyr** package:

```
library(dplyr)
chickwts %>% 
  count(feed) %>%
  filter(n > 11)
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

       feed  n
1    casein 12
2   linseed 12
3   soybean 14
4 sunflower 12
```